# Letting superclass's methods be implemented by an inherited class

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, code-structure

Say I have this structure for my code:

```
public abstract class A{ 
    public abstract Foo methodX();
    public abstract Bar methodY();
}

public class B extends A {
    public Foo methodX(){
        // stuff
    }
    public Bar methodY(){
        // more stuff
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    public Foo methodX() {
        // stuff
    }
    public Bar methodY(){
        // What to do?
    }
}

public class D extends C {
    public Bar methodY() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class F extends C {
    public Bar methodY() {
        // do different stuff
    }
}
```

The reason for me to do this is because I have multiple `class`es extending `A`, all have common method `methodX()` and `methodY()` and I have multiple `class`es extending `B` all have some common properties to B but need to have different ways of doing `methodY()` and have different `equals/hashcode.`

So, how do I have it so that `B` implements the only `methodX()` but lets C and D implement `methodY()` without returning `null` or doing nothing in `methodY()` for `B`?

Comment: Is class `A` the only one which is  abstract ?

Comment: yes, I need to be able to initialise the rest of the classes

Comment: The point being is that a class cannot be instantiated without knowing what all of its methods will do. Whether that is provided by a (non-abstract) super method, anonymous class, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare class B as abstract

```
public abstract class B extends A{
    public Foo medhodX(){
        // stuff
    }
}
```

By declaring class abstract you allow him not to implement all abstract methods (from superclass or implemented interface). So you can implement only one abstract method and force child class to impleent all remaining abstract methods.

Comment: What if I need to also initiate/create B class?

Comment: What would you expect the behavior to be in such a case? Since you don't provide an implementation of `methodY()`

Comment: You cannot instantiate abstract class because it cannot be fully functional (It doesn't 'know' what to do if someone will invoke methodY).

Comment: @Valentin I want to it for a search and insert algorithm, where I am searching for a class B or C's child classes and invoke the methodY() depending on the circumstance.

Comment: @ShubhamPatel I think you should ask another question where you expand on exactly what you want to do because it’s doesn’t seem specific enough for me